# Crashing when back to parent activity. JSONException: No value for response

Tags: android, json, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity

Parent Activity

```
public class MyPageActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private MyReportsFragment myReportsFragment;
    private BlogsFragment blogsFragment;
    private MyGoalsFragment myGoalsFragment;
    private ZnanieFragment znanieFragment;

    private FragmentManager manager;
    private FragmentTransaction transaction;

    String access_token;
    String userID;
    StringBuilder feedInput;

    JSONObject jsonResponseProfile = null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;

    String username;
    String city;
    String userJob;
    String status;

    URL urlImage;
    Bitmap bmp;
    int imageExist;

    String connectURL;
    Bundle bundle;

    String[] feedType = {"Отчеты", "Блоги", "Цели и желания", "Знания"};
    String[] lifeAreaType = {"Все", "Материальное", "Личность", "Тело и здоровье", "Личная жизнь", "Стиль жизни"};
    String selectFeed = "Отчеты";
    String selectSphere = "Все";


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_page);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();

        manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
        myReportsFragment = new MyReportsFragment();
        blogsFragment = new BlogsFragment();
        myGoalsFragment = new MyGoalsFragment();
        znanieFragment = new ZnanieFragment();

        access_token = getIntent().getStringExtra("access_token");
        userID = getIntent().getStringExtra("userID");

        new GetMyProfile().execute();

        connectURL = "http://upgrade.im/api/method/wall.actions?access_token=" + access_token;
        bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("connectURL", connectURL);
        myReportsFragment.setArguments(bundle);
        transaction = manager.beginTransaction();
        transaction.add(R.id.myPageReportFeed, myReportsFragment);
        transaction.commit();

        // адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterFeedType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_row, feedType);
        adapterFeedType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        final Spinner feedTypeSp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerFeedTypeMyPage);
        feedTypeSp.setAdapter(adapterFeedType);


        // устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
        feedTypeSp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {               
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        // адаптер
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapterLifeAreaType = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.spinner_row, lifeAreaType);
        adapterFeedType.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        final Spinner lifeAreaTypeSp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerLifeAreaTypeMyPage);
        lifeAreaTypeSp.setAdapter(adapterLifeAreaType);

        // устанавливаем обработчик нажатия
        lifeAreaTypeSp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {            
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });
    }

    private class GetMyProfile extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL("http://upgrade.im/api/method/profile.get?access_token=" + access_token + "&rettype=full");

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                feedInput = new StringBuilder();
                String inputBufferSymbol = "";
                while ((inputBufferSymbol = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    feedInput.append(inputBufferSymbol);
                }
                br.close();


                jsonResponseProfile = new JSONObject(feedInput.toString());
                jsonResponse = jsonResponseProfile.getJSONObject("response");

                if (jsonResponse.has("first_name")) {
                    username = jsonResponse.getString("first_name");
                } else {
                    username = jsonResponse.getString("login");
                }

                if (jsonResponse.getString("online").equals("1")) {
                    status = "online";
                } else {
                    status = "offline";
                }

                if (jsonResponse.has("city")) {
                    city = jsonResponse.getString("city");
                } else {
                }

                if (jsonResponse.has("activity")) {
                    userJob = jsonResponse.getString("activity");
                } else {
                }

                if (jsonResponse.has("photo")) {
                    urlImage = new URL("http://upgrade.im/upload/avatar/" + jsonResponse.getString("photo"));
                    imageExist = 1;
                } else {
                    imageExist = 0;
                }


            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            FillProfile();
        }
    }

    private void FillProfile() {

        TextView myPageUsername = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPageUsernameAge);
        TextView myPageCity = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPageUserCity);
        TextView myPageUserJob = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPageUserJob);
        TextView myPageStatus = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.myPageStatus);
        ImageView userAvatar = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.userAvatar);


        myPageUsername.setText(username);
        myPageCity.setText(city);
        myPageUserJob.setText(userJob);
        myPageStatus.setText(status);

        if (imageExist == 1) {
            Glide.with(this).load(urlImage.toString()).into(userAvatar);
        } else {
            userAvatar.setImageDrawable(null);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_my_page, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {

        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(MyPageActivity.this, AllNewsActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("access_token", access_token);
            startActivity(intent);
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Fragment attached to this activity

```
public class MyReportsFragment extends Fragment {

    Button buttonToStart;
    Button buttonPrevReport;
    Button buttonNextReport;
    int reportID;

    JSONObject jsonResponseReports = null;
    JSONObject jsonResponse;
    JSONArray items;


    String linkGoal;
    String report;
    String goalType;
    String sphere;
    String timeStamp;

    ImageView spheraTypeIcon;
    LinearLayout linkGoalImageView;
    TextView linkGoalText;
    TextView reportText;
    TextView timeView;

    StringBuilder feedInput;

    String connectURL;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        connectURL = getArguments().getString("connectURL");
        reportID=0;

        View reportsFragment = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_my_reports_line, null);

        buttonNextReport = (Button) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.buttonNextReport);
        buttonPrevReport = (Button) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.buttonPreviousReport);
        buttonToStart = (Button) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.toStartButton);
        spheraTypeIcon = (ImageView) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.spheraTypeIcon);
        linkGoalImageView = (LinearLayout) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.linkGoalImageView);
        linkGoalText = (TextView) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.linkGoalText);
        reportText = (TextView) reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.reportText);
        timeView = (TextView)reportsFragment.findViewById(R.id.timeView);

        new GetReportFeed().execute();       

        return reportsFragment;
    }

    private class GetReportFeed extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            try {

                URL url = new URL(connectURL);

                HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
                connection.setDoOutput(true); // Triggers POST.
                connection.setDoInput(true);

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(connection.getInputStream()));
                feedInput = new StringBuilder();
                String inputBufferSymbol = "";
                while ((inputBufferSymbol = br.readLine()) != null) {
                    feedInput.append(inputBufferSymbol);
                }
                br.close();

                jsonResponseReports = new JSONObject(feedInput.toString());
                jsonResponse = jsonResponseReports.getJSONObject("response");
                items = jsonResponse.getJSONArray("items");
                JSONObject item0 = items.getJSONObject(0);
                JSONObject item0user = item0.getJSONObject("user");
                JSONObject item0userGoal = item0.getJSONObject("map_block");
                linkGoal = item0userGoal.getString("title");
                goalType = item0userGoal.getString("type");
                report = item0.getString("description");
                sphere = item0.getString("sphere");
                timeStamp = item0.getString("time");

            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
            FillReport();
        }
    }

    private void FillReport() {

        switch (sphere) {
            case "1":
                spheraTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.material);
                break;
            case "2":
                spheraTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.lichnost);
                break;
            case "3":
                spheraTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.tiz);
                break;
            case "4":
                spheraTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.lj);
                break;
            case "5":
                spheraTypeIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.stj);
                break;
        }

        switch (goalType) {
            case "goal":
                linkGoalImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#f7846a"));
                break;
            case "desire":
                linkGoalImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#8EF165"));
                break;
            case "act":
                linkGoalImageView.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#F9D753"));
                break;
        }

        linkGoalText.setText(linkGoal);
        reportText.setText(report);

        Date normalDateTime = new java.util.Date(Integer.parseInt(timeStamp) * 1000L);
        SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss z");
        timeView.setText(format.format(normalDateTime.getTime()+TimeZone.getDefault().getRawOffset()));
    }

}
```

Through the menu item I go to child activity, and when I back to parent activity I get

> org.json.JSONException: No value for response

But Why? I put all important code to `onStart()` for repeat all generate-activity-processes when I back to parent activity and all data must be ready already.

Comment: please go through http://developer.android.com/training/basics/activity-lifecycle/index.html and understand about activity life cycle in depth.

Comment: i guided this scheme http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/lifecycle.php but something i missed. Please, explain me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i find answer. Hardware back button works perfectly, but action bar back button doing something wrong, so i find how rewrite action bar back button behave.

```
@Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            if (item.getItemId() == android.R.id.home) {
                    onBackPressed();
                    return true;
            }
            return false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[image: Activity Life Cycle]

**Main Activity Started**

```
E/Main Activity﹕ onCreateView()
E/Main Activity﹕ onCreate()
E/Main Activity﹕ onStart()
E/Main Activity﹕ onResume()
E/Main Activity﹕ onCreateOptionsMenu()
```

**Button Clicked to open second Activity**

```
E/Main Activity﹕ onPause()
E/Second Activity﹕ onCreateView()
E/Second Activity﹕ onCreate()
E/Second Activity﹕ onStart()
E/Second Activity﹕ onResume()
E/Second Activity﹕ onCreateOptionsMenu()
E/Main Activity﹕ onStop()
```

**Back button pressed**

```
E/Second Activity﹕ onPause()
E/Main Activity﹕ onRestart()
E/Main Activity﹕ onStart()
E/Main Activity﹕ onResume()
E/Second Activity﹕ onStop()
E/Second Activity﹕ onDestroy()
```

Try putting `onStart()` code in `onCreate()`.

Comment: actually i moved code from oncreate to onstart  because this issue, but it didnt help. Problem on fragment, i think. He isn't wait receive data, though fill view method call on onPostExecute...

Comment: onPostExecute() will only be executed after doInBackground() has finished its execution. Are you sure you are getting response from the url in the background process.?

Comment: Whoa! I found that hardware back button works right (activity and fragment loads perfectly), and only back button on action bar call exception...